# Android Espresso Configure Shards by Class

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso, spoon, android-studio-dolphin

For Android Espresso Testing, i'm using the following commands to run our tests:

```
    ./gradlew pixel4api30DebugAndroidTest 
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Suites.TestSuite 
-Pandroid.experimental.androidTest.numManagedDeviceShards=2
```

This splits all the tests in the TestSuites across 2 pixel 4 emulators.

If I have the following in the TestSuite:

TestClass1

- Test1
- Test2
- Test3

TestClass2

- Test1
- Test2
- Test3

It may run TestClass1.Test1 on 1 emulator and TestClass1.Test2 on emulator 2.  (it could pick any emulator to run any of the tests on).

Is there a way to force it to split the shards by TestClasses?  So it will run TestClass1 and all tests on one emulator, TestClass2 and all tests on an emulator.

I believe if you have used Spoon in the past, you may have been able to accomplish this by using singleInstrumentationCall property as noted here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/gradle-spoon-plugin

Comment: Hello, any progress on this? Having the same question...

Comment: Unfortunately no